# Searching for text in square brackets in Azure Boards Query Editor

Tags: azure-devops

I want to search for a word in square brackets in the title of my work items. But the work items that include the same word not in square brackets are also listed.

The solution that works for tsql does not work for azure query. It doesn't work when I search for '[[]MyWord]%' as I do in SQL. How can I list work items that only contain the word in square brackets?

For example I want to find work item titled Hello [World], but I don't want to list work item titled Hello World.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpF0r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Operator to **Contains** instead of Contains Words.
There is a sample. I have two work items named "Hello World" and "Hello [World]".
[image]

When I set the Operator to Contains, it will only return "Hello [World]".
[image]

When I set the Operator to Contains Words, it will return both work items.
[image]

Comment: I also tried the Contains keyword, but it did not list the results because I wrote the word I was looking for in quotation marks. When I write without quotes, the results were listed as I wanted. Thank you for your answer.